# Required attribute not working when it's a select in .net core mvc form validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It's a simple form page. The framework is .NET Core 3.1 and this page is basically coded following the Microsoft tutorial.

Model

```
public class ProdoctModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string product { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string locale { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string category { get; set; }

        public bool importGoods { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var countries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("en-US", "United States"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ch-CN", "China"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("es-MX", "Mexico") };
            var categories = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "foods"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "3C"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "medicine") };
            ViewBag.countries = new SelectList(countries, "Key", "Value");
            ViewBag.categories = categories;
            return View();
        }
```

view

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="text-center">
                Add Product
            </h3>
            <form role="form" asp-controller="PrsExps" asp-action="Create" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="product"></label>
                    <input asp-for="product" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" asp-validation-for="product" ></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="price"></label>
                    <input asp-for="price" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" asp-validation-for="price"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="locale"></label>
                    <select asp-for="locale" asp-items="@ViewBag.countries">
                        <option>Please Select...</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" asp-validation-for="locale"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="category"></label>
                    @foreach (var catItem in ViewBag.categories)
                    {
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" asp-for="category" id="category@(catItem.Key)" value="@catItem.Value">
                            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="category">@catItem.Value</label>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" asp-validation-for="category"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="importGoods" /> Imported
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Here is a screenshot when I enter notion and click submit button directly. As you can see, the required validation on 'locale' is missing.
[image]

Comment: You are not validating other fields in your HTML ?

Comment: Well, you don’t have `asp-validation-for` spans for two other fields

Comment: Don't radio buttons and dropdowns have defaults?

Comment: @Kaj I've appended more detail. Other fields are validated.

Comment: @Alex Skalozub Still not working on 'locale' field even it was added

Comment: @Anoop R Desai  No, the dropdowns have no defaul value

Comment: @wtf512 you need to explicitly specify `value=""` for your “please select” option, because option text is used as value when the `value` attribute is not specified.

Comment: Yes. After I added the default value "", the error message showed up when I clicked submit. Thanks!